# Selecting 10% random number from a infinite stream

Tags: database, algorithm, postgresql, hadoop

There is a stream of numbers coming. At any point of time i might need 10% random numbers.
I obviously don't want to store the entire stream.

The bigger problem is for which i am thinking the above algorithm.
I have lot of data(timestamp based) which goes into the database. Now i also want to build a sample table which contains say 10% of the records in main database table but random, so that if want to query fast and i am okay with little inaccuracy i can query fast.
I receive message(numbers) in batches say say sometimes 100 , sometimes 20 sometimes 5 etc.

I was thinking i will do it while streaming which the problem in question indicates.
Can some one suggest a good algorithm for this.
Is there a better way ?

Comment: I'd make sure you understand exactly how the stream is "random."  White-noise random, or is there a correlation from one number to the next (even if it's not predictable)?  If there is a correlation, and you grab your 10% 100 numbers at a time, the sample may not represent what you want.

Comment: the numbers does not have any co-relation , say they all are the time spent by customers in restraunt. So i want to query what is the avg time spent in the restraunt between a particular time interval and as my normal table is pretty large , i want to do it over sampled data.
The problem of grabbing 10% at a time is if i always receive say less then 10 message in batch , then 10% will always be null

Comment: @Peter For a mathematically sound model that you can fine tune, be sure to take a look at my answer below. I think it addresses all of the concerns you've raised so far.

Answer (score 3):

The easy solution is to just save every 10th incoming data point, but this could potentially lead to biased results depending on just how random the data is.

If you want to simulate a truly random 10% sample on an incoming stream, you can use the [Poisson Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), with a mean of 9, to decide how many entries to skip before logging the next one.  It's probably a good idea to set a cap though, so you don't wind up with rare, yet predictably large gaps in the data.

Comment: This is *equivalent* to saying for each item, independently, "keep it with probability 0.1." - "simulate a truly random 10% sample" is a bit of an overstatement, though I agree it's still "more random" than a regular sampling of every 10th item.

Answer (score 1):

## Formulation

Here's how I would formulate the problem. Let the items in your (potentially infinite) sequence be `i=1,2,...`. Suppose you want to take approximately `0 < z < 1` of the items from your sequence, to generate a sparser sequence. Let `x(i)` represent whether we include item `i` in the sparser sequence we generate.

For any window of `n` consecutive items (where you pick `n >= 1`), you want the *expected* number of items to be `z*n`, but with the possibility for some *variance* from that expectation. For this you could use a (truncated) binomial distribution [(link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with mean `z*n` and standard deviation `d` (where you pick `d > 0`). (It's truncated on the right because it would be impossible for you to pick more than `n` items when there are only `n` to consider! You could also truncate it on the left to say "I always want *at least* `m` items out of every `n`, where `m` is much less than `z*n`, but I'll assume you skip that.)

Now, you can determine the probability you should include the item `i` in the sparser sequence you are generating based on whether you have included each of the `n-1` preceding items `i-1,i-2,...,i-(n-1)`:

```
A = P( x(i) = 1 | x(i - j), 1 <= j < n )
```

## What does this all mean?

The way this is formulated, you pick three numbers:

- `0 < z < 1`

  - In your question, you have specified `z` to be 10% - i.e., `z = 0.1`
- `n >= 1` and `d > 0`

  - Think of `n` as a window size
  - Think of `d` as the amount of deviation from a regular sampling towards a more noisy sampling pattern
  - `n = 1` means "include every item `i` with probability `z`, independently of whether other items are included in the sparser sequence
  - `n = 100, d = 0.0001` means "except in extremely rare cases, include `10` out of each consecutive `100` items in the sparser sequence"

    - if you make `d` extremely small, you're basically saying "choose every `1/z`th item, in a regular pattern"
  - `n = 100, d = 5` means "include roughly `5` to `15` out of each consecutive `100` items in the sparser sequence"

Answer (score 0):

Taking your example in the comments:

- There is no correlation between the data.
- You want a sample at particular times of the day.

In this case, you can keep track of the total number of data that have come through during each time interval -- say, per half hour the restaurant is open.  (Or even just a 0 to 9 counter that resets at zero when you reach ten.)

Grab the first one you see during each time interval, let nine drop on the floor.

Rinse and repeat, and you should build up a good 10% sampling for each time interval.

Comment: it wont be random , you r picking every 10th in 1 way